# Laravel blade - double echo statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am already inside a `{!! !!}`

```
{!! do_shortcode('[searchandfilter id="27"]') !!}
```

I am now passing data to this partial file, and need to update that id=""

My thought was to add: `{{ }}` however it's not printing out because I am already inside of the `{!! !!}`.

```
{!! do_shortcode('[searchandfilter id="{{ $form_id }}"]') !!}
```

Any idea how to concatenate this $form_id inside this blade echo?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, forgot to try the regular concatenation method:

```
{!! do_shortcode('[searchandfilter id="'. $form_id .'"]') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue is that you used simple quotes `''`. PHP doesn't parse PHP variables inside those.

The following options should work:

```php
{!! do_shortcode("[searchandfilter id='{$form_id}']") !!}
```

or

```php
{!! do_shortcode("[searchandfilter id='$form_id']") !!}
```